# Bound on non-negative rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, upper-lower-bounds

Let $J$ be all one matrix and $A$ be a non-negative matrix such that $J-A$ is also non-negative. Then what can we say about the non-negative rank of $J-A$ in terms of the non-negative rank of $A$. We know that for rank, we have

$$\mbox{rank}(A)-1 \le \mbox{rank}(J-A) \le \mbox{rank}(A)+1$$

by subadditive property of rank. Can we bound the non-negative rank of $J-A$ similarly in terms of the non-negative rank of $A$? We can apply subadditivity for non-negative rank but we would have to ensure that matrices are non-negative and will give us following

$$\mbox{rank}_{+}(J) - \mbox{rank}_{+}(A) \le \mbox{rank}_{+}(J-A)$$

which is useless. Can we say more? How far can the non-negative rank of $J-A$ be from $A$?

Any help, comments, hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, is there a special reason why you always say "non-negative rank" instead of just "rank" ? Is it a different notion from the usual rank ?

Comment: Yes, the non-negative rank is different from the usual rank. In non-negative rank, the decomposition is restricted to non-negative rank-one matrices. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_rank_(linear_algebra)